# Objeto não é atualizado

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

No meu fluxo é assim:

- Já possuo um objeto armazenado no banco de dados.
- Ao carregar minha página, estes objetos são buscados no banco, tratados para serem exibidos.
- Os objetos chegam em uma Lista (`List`), dessa é iterada por um `for` para receber os devidos tratamentos.
- Enquanto um objeto é tratado, eu faço uma consulta de `webservice` recebendo um outro objeto. Faço uma comparação entre os objetos e caso haja diferença, o objeto que veio do banco precisa ser atualizado.

Basicamente é isso, o problema ocorre é que eu atualizo meu objeto e mando atualizar no banco mas não atualiza. Alguém pode me dar um help ?

O método que busca no banco:

```
public void pesquisar() {
        List<Objeto> objetos = new ArrayList<>();
        objetos = service.findAll();
        this.encomendas = new ArrayList<>();
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(objetos)) {
            try {
                for (Objeto objeto : objetos) {
                    houveAlteracao(objeto);
                    ajustarInformacoes(objeto);
                }
                ordenarLista();
                horaAtualizacao = new Date();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Agora o método `houveAlteracao()` :

```
private void houveAlteracao(Objeto objeto) {
        try {
            final Objeto obj = popularObjeto(objeto.getCodigo());
            if (obj.getEventos().size() > objeto.getEventos().size()) {
                objeto.setEventos(obj.getEventos());
                service.update(objeto);
            } else {
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Neste método se `getEventos.size()` que pertence ao objeto pesquisado na `webservice` for maior, o objeto do banco deve receber estes valores e depois atualizado, o problema é que o comando é aplicado mas não atualiza. E por último o comando de atualizar:

```
public void update(Objeto objeto) {
        this.em.merge(objeto);
    }
```

Alguém ajuda por favor ?

Comment: Você tem como acrescentar campos em alguma tabela se for necessário?

Comment: Se o seu objeto for gerenciado pelo Hibernate você deve usar o método `update()` ao invés do `merge()`. Se ele não for gerenciado pelo Hibernate você deve usar o `merge()` e em seguida chamar o método `persist()`. Acho que isso. Sempre me confundo com esses métodos hehe

Comment: @VictorStafusa não entendi sua pergunta.

Comment: O problema na verdade é outro. Vou criar uma nova pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Obrigado a todos que tentaram ajudar, mas lendo este [Artigo](http://blog.triadworks.com.br/jpa-por-que-voce-deveria-evitar-relacionamento-bidirecional) claro pra mim, então assim funcionou:

```
private void houveAlteracao(Long id) {
        try {
            Objeto objeto = service.find(id);
            final Objeto obj = popularObjeto(objeto.getCodigo());
            if (obj.getEventos().size() > objeto.getEventos().size()) {
                Evento evento = obj.getEventos().get(0);
                objeto.getEventos().add(evento);
                evento.setHorario(JsfUtils.stringParaTimestamp(evento.getDataOcorrencia().concat(" ").concat(evento.getHoraOcorrencia())));
                evento.setObjeto(objeto);
                service.update(objeto);
                pesquisar();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```